# get current location without using GPS and without internet in android

Tags: android, gps, location

any one can help me if there is a way to get current latitude and longitude without using GPS since it consumes the power and without internet since i need to get location in places without internet service .

Comment: This class done the job for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333736/locating-current-position-in-android-without-gps/14335343#14335343

Answer (score 1):

Yes...Without GPS and internet connection you can get current location through NETWORK_PROVIDER

Try this code.

```
LocationManager lm = null;
boolean network_enabled = false;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try{
    network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

   if(!network_enabled){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString("Custom message"));
        dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS );
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you cache and offline map and get the user to pick where they are on the map.